# Shared objects between two JRuby instances in one JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jruby

I would like to know if it's possible to share an object between two JRuby instances if they run inside the same JVM?

I already tried to create a singleton java class that got referenced from both JRubies, but it's seems, that each JRuby creates it's own environment and it's own version of that java class.

Does someone know a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the were actually two problems.

1. The variables to be shared have to start with an $-sign (e.g. $databases).
2. The LocalContextScope of the scripting container has to be set to the right value.

If the LocalContextScope is set to "singleton" and "concurrent" something like the following is possible.

```
require 'java'

include Java
import 'org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer'
import 'org.jruby.embed.LocalContextScope'

$a = "Test"

container = ScriptingContainer.new LocalContextScope::CONCURRENT
container.run_scriptlet "puts $a"
```